# How long will a running PHP process get stuck while piling up server's CPU load

Tags: php, apache, process, load, debian

It's already several weeks since occasionaly all 8 CPU cores on server machine got almost to 100% load because of the Apache processes (just Apache, there are no other high-load processes except MySQL).

Restarting Apache always works but usually just for couple hours but once it was even a week. There's no visible pattern. Overall load gets to around 10 but the machine is still respondinng very quickly (usually it's floating from 1 to 4 or 6 tops, depends on daytime). But there is no connection between these never-ending spikes and actual server stress caused by visits or cron jobs. It seems pretty random, so my best guess is a faulty PHP script cycling over and over doing god knows what.

If nothing else, such a useless load is heating up the CPU, shortening his lifetime and who knows how many resources are spent by this PHP process I can't identify.

All the PHP processes are wrapped by Apache processes, so I can't actually see which PHP scripts are currently running in the UNIX process list. Is there any other way around to point to specific script? Other than implement some kind of tracking code inside every PHP script? I'm not running webhosting but there is more than one site and I don't see how could I implement a tracking code in such an extensive code spread across the webserver.

Therefore I'm looking for pure unix solution (Debian). In worst case it would point me to PHP script which includes dozens of PHP classes and contollers. In the best case it would be some simple script. Either way, it's a start. I think.

Comment: first of all, you can enable mod server_status on your apache to see which requests are eating up resources. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html You can also use `strace -p` to attach to a 100% CPU process and see what system calls it is making. that might give you a hint.

Comment: @DvirVolk mod_status doesn't seem to be much helpful but thank you for strace command. Although it leads me to another thing I have to investigate when the load gets high again: Usually Apache processes are spawning and dying, there is no fixed PID I could hold on. In case there is no fixed PID for any of apache processes while the "spike" is in action, does it mean there is no long running php script or the script could actually be transfered from one apache process to another while running?

Comment: why it mod_status not helping? if you enable detailed mode you can see the actual CPU consumption of each script, it's great for that. Anyway, the PHP's PID is apache's PID, same script holds the same process for its entire lifetime.

Comment: @DvirVolk, my bad, I wasn't aware of ExtendedStatus. Anyway there are requests for images and that sort of stuff. Not sure if it points me to the php script I'm looking for but I'll give a try. Also I'll take a closer look to apache's/php's PIDs nextime. To make sure they are not changing, meaning, they still hold the same php script. Although there are usually four or six of them at the same time.

Comment: @Saix the same apache process runs different PHP scripts, of course. Usually scripts that consume 100% CPU run for a long period. BTW could it be a memory issue? Did you check your swapping status? Try and reduce the number of maximum allowed apache workers.

Comment: @DvirVolk: Well, that sounds like something I actually thought I've coped with recently. I hope this isn't the wrong way here at StackExchange, but I'm gonna setup a new question at ServerFault for MaxClient setting. My issues couldn't have to be about faulty script necessarily and there aren't probably more ways to track it anyway [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/370866/could-high-maxclient-value-cause-cpu-load-issues-no-matter-actual-server-stress)

Comment: @DvirVolk It tooks a long time but it's back again. It is not memory leak ( [link](http://saix.cz/pidscreen.jpg) ), there's no output from strace -p, no clues in mod_status and no hanging sql process. Damn I wish I could see what is the thing wrapped by these Apache processes. Can't beleive it can't be achieved some way.

Comment: @saix you can attach a debugger with Xdebug but it usually slows down things so much you won't get a real picture of what's going on. maybe you can try working with php in CGI mode and putting nginx in front instead of apache. this will separate php processes from the web server's processes, and maybe just magically solve this issue while at it.

Comment: I have setup my own little debug tool. Everytime I start the framework, I put current url into database along with PID. At the end of script I remove it. When the load hits again, I'll see the PID of faulty process and I'll search for it in database to find at least the URL of requested page. There's tons of includes but that should give me a real hint.

Answer (score 0):

You may not see the php processes in process list, but you can get their PIDs by this PHP function: getmypid();

In case you're using Debian, get the value returned by the above function, then open a terminal and use the 'top' command:

## top -p xxxx

where xxxx is the PID returned by "getmypid();"

Comment: top -p xxxx simply filter the process list. It is not showing what PHP process is wrapped by the Apache superior process. getmypid() could show the actual PHP process ID but if I know from which php script I should call it, I wouldn't need it.